How to order date and time in BigQuery
I'm working with a dataset that runs from July 1, 2021 to May 31, 2022. I converted the original Excel spreadsheet into a CSV file, but when I run queries and try to ORDER BY date my output starts on 1/1/2022. (The same thing happens when I use the BigQuery "sort" function as well). My date schema is a nullable string and is formatted mm/dd/yyyy with 24-hour time in 10-minute increments (4:40 AM on July 6 is listed as 7/6/2021 4:40). For data analysis and charting/graphing purposes I want the data to run earliest to latest; do I need to cast these dates into a different format (something including time zone?) or is there something else I'm missing?
Thanks!
p.s. I have tried both ordering by date and using the "sort" function and both result in the same result (the data begins at 1/1/2022 instead of 7/1/2021).

Try order by cast(DateColumn as date with format 'm/d/yyyy') if this is all happening within BQ. The better solution is to import and store the data as date in the first place though.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Sorting dates in anything other than YYYY-MM-DD format is going to give unhelpful sort order outputs.
e.g. dates in US date format i.e. mm/dd/yyyy will be sorted in month order, not year or day order.
--generate random dates in format m/d/yyyy HH:MM
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT FORMAT_DATETIME("%m/%d/%Y %R",
    TIMESTAMP_ADD('2010-01-01 00:00:00' , INTERVAL CAST(TIMESTAMP_DIFF('2020-12-31 23:59:59', '2010-01-01 00:00:00', DAY)*RAND() AS INT64) DAY)) AS dates
  FROM
    UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 10))
)

--sort by yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM while leaving the original values intact
SELECT dates
FROM table1
ORDER BY FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y/%m/%d %R",PARSE_DATETIME("%m/%d/%Y %R",dates))


I’m going to try re-ordering them in Excel first and see if that does the trick—thanks!

ps—does it matter if it’s yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm or should it be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm? Thanks again.

It doesn’t matter what the delimiter in the date is. So long as it recognises the date parts e.g. YYYY etc then you’re good. That’s where the FORMAT_DATETIME function comes in to it.

In Excel, copy the values into a new column and on that column set the format from the Format=>Custom options. One of the available options is yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm.
